# How do I create a windows phone start screen layout in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I just started a new xamarin forms application where I want the main page to show a list of boxes containing pictures and text in the same way as the windows phone start screen. Is this something that can be achieved with the listview combined with a grid? How would I go ahead implementing this?

Comment: Is content something dynamic? Otherwise a Grid could be enough...

Comment: I saw a tutorial once to archive that style, when i find it i'll edit this comment and added the link. Till then you can do it by using [FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView)

Comment: Yes the content will be dynamic. Each row can have between 1 to 6 items or boxes but there can be an undefined number of rows.